# Data structure for pixel selections in a picture

Tags: image, image-processing, data-structures

Is there a convenient data structure for storing a pixel selection in a picture?

By pixel selection I mean a set of pixels you obtain with selection tools such as those in image editing software (rectangles, lasso, magic wand, etc.). there can be holes, and in the general case the selection is (much) smaller than the picture itself.

The objective is to be able to save/load selections, display the selected pixels only is a separate view (bounding box size), using selections in specific algorithms (typically algorithms requiring segmentation), etc. It should use as little memory space as possible since the objective is to store a lot of them in a DB.

Solutions I found so far:

- a boolean array (size of the picture/8)
- a list of (uint16,uint16) => unefficient if many pixels in the selection
- an array of lists: lists of pixels series for each line

Comment: For rectangles and lasso you should think of storing polygons (array of coordinates). You can manipulate these e.g. to remove redundant points. For magic-wand type selections, where the outline is very complex, the most efficient is a binary image (boolean mask). You can limit this to the bounding box of the selection, and add an offset to know where in the image to apply it to.

Comment: The rectangle is pretty obvious, I wish my case always applies to this. :) The combinaison of boolean + bounding box + position is interesting. I'll give it a shot if there is no better proposition.

Comment: It depends in part on how you want to use the selections.  Masks can be weighty but are very general and very useful for certain types of operations.  A sorted list of horizontal spans works well with certain types of operations but only if the selected region is largely contiguous.

Comment: I see, this is why I explained a little what I would like to do with my selections in the text. Maybe not detailed enough.

Comment: I am thinking that I can give another detail: selections will be handwritten words. So large and not high bounding box, lot of holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A boolean array will take W x H bits for the raster plus extra accounting (such as ROI limits). This is roughly proportional to the area of the bounding box.

A list of pixel coordinates will take like 32 bits (2x16 bits) per selected pixel. This is pretty large compared to the boolean array, except when the selection is very hollow.

Another useful representation is the run-length-encoding, which counts the continguous pixels row by row. This representation will take about 16 bits per run. Said differently, 16 / n bits per pixel when the average length of the runs is n pixels. This works fine for large filled shapes, but poorly for isolated pixels.

Finally, you can also consider just storing the outlines of the shapes as a list of pixels (32 bits per pixel) or as a Freeman chain (only 3 bits per pixel), which can be a significant saving with respect to the full enumeration.

As you can see, the choice is uneasy because the efficiency of the different representations is strongly dependent on the shape of the selection. Another important aspect is the ease with which the given representation can be used for the targeted processing of the selection.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am wondering if there is (are) a clever data structure in the image processing literature. Is it this?

Comment: @Tom: I don't get your question.

Comment: Are these solutions best of thought or standards in the image processing literarure?

Comment: @tom: they are commonplace in image processing litterature and at the same time easy to reinvent. (Using outlines is unusual, but Freeman coding makes them attractive.)

Comment: I think I'll go with boolean array of the bounding box + position in the picture. I have to be able to have multiple independent selections, with possible overlaps. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tom: all these structures support overlapping !?

Comment: If I use separate boolean arrays for each selections, there can be overlaps. I remember about data structures for arrays with holes, but I don't remember exactly how they are coded. I have to investigate this.

Comment: @Tom: I don't understand why you focus on overlaps when all structures allow this.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer because of the question mark. The focus is just because of my needs. But as you said, all the structures allow it. Everything is fine.